# What is this regex supposed to do? ^[\d\D]{1,}$

Tags: regex, preg-match

I'm not exactly a pro when it comes to regex and I have a PHP script that runs things through this regex:

```
^[\d\D]{1,}$
```

What does this supposed to do, it seems that it matches everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short all that regex is doing is this:

```
^.+$
```

Which means match any character (digits OR non-digits) of 1 or greater length.

Answer (score 2):

- `\d` matches any digit
- `\D` matches any non-digit.
- `[\d\D]` matches all digits and non-digits.
- `{1,}` asks for the match in `[]` to be repeated at least 1 time (with no upper limit).

So it matches everything with at least 1 character in it.

Reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

`^[\d\D]{1,}$` will match a string which contains one or more `{1,}` of any digit `\d` or non-digit `\D` character *including* newline characters.

In contrast `^.+$` will match a string containing one or more of any character *except* newlines. If the singleline modifier was added to the regex, i.e. `/^.+$/s` then the `.` would also match any character including newlines.

`[\d\D]` is equivalent to using `.` in singleline mode, although more commonly `[\s\S]` is used with the same result.

`+` is equivalent to `{1,}`.

The regex will match the whole of any string that contains at least one character of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. In fact anything that is at least one character long. But in a kind of overcomplicated and pointless way. `[\d\D]` is equivalent to `.` and `{1,}` is equivalent to `+`